# Boost thread: Start thread **after** construction (not in constructor)

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

In my code I want to (at least in debug builds) ensure that certain functions are only executed in a specific thread. More specifically consider the following class:

```
class MyClass {
    private:
        boost::thread m_thread;

        void doStart();

    public:
        void start();
};
```

The implementation of `start` is

```
void MyClass::start() {
    m_thread = boost::thread(&MyClass::doStart, this);
}
```

aka: It creates a new thread and executes the `doStart` function in that new thread. Furthermore it stores this new thread in a member variable.

At the beginning of `doStart` there is a check for the thread it is executing in:

```
void MyClass::doStart() {
    assert(m_thread.get_id() == boost::this_thread::get_id());
}
```

That is supposed to ensure that `doStart` will only ever be run inside the class's own worker thread stored in `m_thread`.

Most times this works just fine but every now and again this assertion fails. After having thought about it for a while I have a few theories that I think could be viable:

1. Calling `get_id()` right at the beginning of a thread's execution might be problematic (potentially some sort of race-condition inside boost)
2. There is a race-condition between executing `doStart` and the assignment of `m_thread` so that sometimes `doStart` access the uninitialized `m_thread` variable before it is assigned its value
3. The assignment of `m_thread` is ill-formed since as maybe it is unintentionally invoking a copy-constructor of the thread-object (which might alter the ID)

From these possibilities I think 2) is the most likely. If this is the case, my question would be: From what I have found, I can't assign the thread to `m_thread` and then launch it. Therefore I can't ensure that `m_thread` has been initialized before `doStart` runs in the new thread.

The only solution I could come up with is to introduce an additional member variable `std::atomic<bool>` that is initialized to `false` and is only set to `true` *after* `m_thread` has been assigned. In `doStart` I'd then perform active waiting on that condition before validating the thread's ID. This doesn't seem very appealing to me though. Is there a better approach to this?

Comment: Maybe just use a mutex if you need synchronization? `lock_guard guard(m_mutex); m_thread = ...;` ... `doStart() { lock_guard guard(m_mutex); assert(m_thread.get_id() == boost::this_thread::get_id()); }`

Comment: @dewaffled yes that would also be an alternative to the boolean flag. I still don't like that approach all that much because to me it would make more sense to "simply" start the thread only after I have assigned it to the respective variable. That would avoid having to carry a mutex/flag in the class that is only ever needed for that particular situation. But I guess your suggestion is probably better than active waiting, so thanks for the hint :)

Comment: Right. This is definitely a racecondition - in fact its undefined behaviour. Win32 threads API has a CREATE_SUSPENDED but boost doesn't have this. Its fairly easy to implement though using the ideas from dewaffled or another similar system.

Comment: As an alternative to the mutex, use a boost::barrier at beginning of the thread.

Comment: @SvenNilsson is there an intrinsic advantage of using a barrier over using a mutex in this situation?

Comment: Not really, except that the barrier was explicitly designed to make the thread stop at a certain point, while the mutex is designed for exclusive access to data. Both provide memory synchronization however - any data written by thread A before the barrier, can be safely read by thread B after the barrier..

Comment: Okay thanks for the clarification :)